# DevExpress type filters on HTML table

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-plugins, grid, devexpress

I'm having hard time figuring out way to put DevExpress look alike filters on HTML table. The reason I cannot use DevExpress grid is because my grid (html table) will be having few actions that kinda not possible using DevExpress grid. I would prefer any Jquery extension instead that will give a filter row to enter values along with a combo filter right into the column's header name. Like the screenshot attached. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

the screenshot attached is of DevExpress grid, I want to use same filters on HTML tables. Is there anyone who have used any such plugin?

Comment: There are numerous plugins that offer such filtering...and they aren't hard to find. Try DataTables for example

Comment: @charlietfl Datatable doesn't provide the kind of filters I want i.e. one row to enter filter values along with a filter icon in header that behaves like dropdown as soon as you clicks on it.

Comment: Sure it does, you just have to customize it to do what you want